# Finding all combinations of inequalities describing a sub-space in an arrangement of hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, geometry

Given an arbitrary arrangement of M hyperplanes with N-1 dimensions in a N-dimensional linear space, we can identify any of the resulting convex sub-spaces using a combination of hyperplanes as inequalities, either greater or less than 0.

In my problem, the known elements are the linear equations describing the hyperplanes (plus the boundaries of the convex N-dimensional space, which can also be expressed as hyperplanes) and all the points of intersection between the hyperplanes.
My goal is to compute, as efficiently as possible, all of the possible combinations of hyperplanes which determine a sub-space.

For instance, the number of all possible combinations of inequalities resulting from M hyperplanes would be 2^M, but many of these combinations are conflicting and it is known that the actual number is exponential over N rather than M due to geometrical constraints, giving me hope that a more efficient approach is possible.
Additionally, even if I were to use a naive approach such as listing all possible combinations of inequalities, I would still need to determine the significant ones (i.e. the ones actually bounding any specific sub-space).

One idea I had would be to compute all of the segments between the intersection points and solve this using a graph-based approach, but that sounds very expensive.

This problem is inherently exponential, but I was wondering if any feasible solution is known.